# Resource owner password flow signature check

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token

I've an issue and would like to if this is just not supported, or if I'm doing something wrong.

I've a native app (winforms) and would like to perform token requests from it, using resource owner password flow (sending both client and user credentials) (implicit flow through a webview kind of works, but I don't like having to keep that webview around in order to keep the auth cookie alive).

First issue is that I'm basically trying to establish identity in the native app, and since I'm stuck to using resource owner password flow, I'm stuck to using access tokens. Is this safe? I'm familiar with a vulnerability in using access tokens (OAuth2) in establishing identity. Which is why id tokens (OpenID Connect) are recommended, but the IdServer I'm using doesn't support that. So then is that safe? If I can't check the audience field to make sure the received token is really meant for my client?

Secondly, if I use access tokens through resource owner password flow, is it mandatory to perform the same signature check on the token? Considering the TLS channel should offer protection in transit.

Thanks, and I hope someone can clear this for me.